# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request (email account creator)

Tags: c#

I am receiving this error in my email account creator. I don't know where the issue could be... It worked until the last week. It keeps saying that the account already exists. I am doing it with C#.

I have:

> confirmationBox, confirmationBox.Designer,ControlPanel,
>   ControlPanel.Designer,LoginBox,LoginBox.Designer,Program
>   andRandomPassword.

If it comes to your mind where could the problem be, please let me know, this is driving me crazy.

And the user doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe the account already exists?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more detail in your question about what *exactly* your situation looks like (code etc, setup etc). Have a look [**here for a guide on how to ask *good* questions**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers).

Comment: Hi all, the user doesn't exist, that's why is weird. It was working and the last week it started to give me this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server error, it has nothing to do with C#.

Check if the account already exists, try to create an other account.
You could also check the case sensitivity of your email server.

Comment: `4xx` errors mean the client has made an invalid request, not that the server has caused an error.

Comment: By server error I meant the server threw the error ... still it has nothing to do with C# when it says the account already exists.

Comment: It's also possible that the email account creator is returning a 400 error when the account already exists. There isn't enough detail in the question to understand what is going on.

Comment: Hi all, the user doesn't exist, that's why is weird. It was working and the last week it started to give me this error.